# High number of block bounces reported this week for some reason

Tags: marketing-cloud, bounce-management

I'm in the beginning stages of IP Warming for my client, and the first week had a very high deliverability rate - 99%-100%.  This week, we're experiencing around 84% deliverability with a very high number of block bounces reported.

The same email is going out (compared from last week to this week).  The same sender profile is being chosen, the same IP address.  I'm curious what might be causing this?  I did extract the Bounce data to a flat file and it did not have any relevant information on there as to more details around the block bounce and what might be causing it.  I've opened up a Salesforce Support Ticket to see if they could dig into it - but, does anyone here have any idea why this might be happening?

EDIT:

It appears that an SMTPBounceReason is:

```
5.3.2 (system not accepting network messages) resimta-po-28v.sys.comcast.net resimta-po-28v.sys.comcast.net 13.111.103.190 found on one or more DNSBLs, see postmaster.comcast.net/smtp-error-codes.php#BL000010";
```

Most of the SMTPMessages mention blacklists.  But what is weird is that this was working 100% perfectly with the same email last week - I'm only sending between 4-7k emails a day for IP Warming (a lot less than usual, I know).  I did cross reference the IP address with some blacklist sites and I can't seem to find any sites that have my IP blacklisted.

Comment: It is likely an issue in deliverability - most issues here stem from volume and frequency to each email client. What you should look at is which domain/email clients are getting bounced back and then reference the history of sending to those and compare to IP warmup best practices.

Comment: Also, as I noticed your sample referenced Comcast, I wanted to link this deliverability docs for you to reference: https://fulcrumtech.net/resources/optimize-email-deliverability-comcast/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was because the sending email address was not actually authenticated.  I updated the sender profile's "send from" email address to be that of the authenticated domain.

Comment: Thank you for posting your resolution - it is much appreciated so that others with the same issue can see what solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First: The MailProvider might have changed their configuration.

Second: You might have gotten on a spam list

Third: You might have been sending to fast

Fourth: Your Content might have been bad that some mail server filter it as spam

Fifth: You should consider giving us more information. Query the _Bounce dataview with SQL and give us the smtpbouncereason and smtpmessage https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_bounce.htm&type=5

Comment: Hi @Johannes it appears that the SMTPBounceReasonis: 5.3.2 (system not accepting network messages) resimta-po-28v.sys.comcast.net resimta-po-28v.sys.comcast.net 13.111.103.190 found on one or more DNSBLs, see http://postmaster.comcast.net/smtp-error-codes.php#BL000010"

Comment: Could a change at the DNS level affected this?  Like I said this was working 100% perfectly.  I cross-referenced the IP address in question with any blacklist "lists" and I can't seem to find any that the IP address is on, so this is very weird.